# Devise is only routing one of the two user Models correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I can't seem to figure out why Devise is falling back to the gem views for one* of the user models.

Here are my routes and the link that I'm using to connect to the new action for the registration form.

Available Devise Routes

```
                 POST   /registration.biz_user(.:format)             devise/registrations#create
           biz_users_sign_out GET    /biz_users/sign_out(.:format)                devise/sessions#destroy
         new_biz_user_session GET    /biz_users/login(.:format)                   devise/sessions#new
             biz_user_session POST   /biz_users/login(.:format)                   devise/sessions#create
     destroy_biz_user_session DELETE /biz_users/logout(.:format)                  devise/sessions#destroy
            biz_user_password POST   /biz_users/password(.:format)                devise/passwords#create
        new_biz_user_password GET    /biz_users/password/new(.:format)            devise/passwords#new
       edit_biz_user_password GET    /biz_users/password/edit(.:format)           devise/passwords#edit
                              PATCH  /biz_users/password(.:format)                devise/passwords#update
                              PUT    /biz_users/password(.:format)                devise/passwords#update
 cancel_biz_user_registration GET    /biz_users/cancel(.:format)                  devise/registrations#cancel
        biz_user_registration POST   /biz_users(.:format)                         devise/registrations#create
    new_biz_user_registration GET    /biz_users/register(.:format)                devise/registrations#new
   edit_biz_user_registration GET    /biz_users/edit(.:format)                    devise/registrations#edit
                              PATCH  /biz_users(.:format)                         devise/registrations#update
                              PUT    /biz_users(.:format)                         devise/registrations#update
                              DELETE /biz_users(.:format)                         devise/registrations#destroy
```

Link to registration Route/URL

```
<%= link_to 'Sign Up', new_biz_user_registration_path, class: 'button success large expand' %>
```

The views for this user model are in Views/bizusers/registrations/..etc.

```
devise_for :biz_users, path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', sign_up: 'register' }
  devise_for :users, path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', sign_up: 'register' }
  devise_for :admins, path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', sign_up: 'register' }
```

Answer (score 1):

What are your models? Because you created routes only for biz_users. Basically if you have many devise models you can create routes for each one. For example, if you have models user and admin you should do it like this:

```
devise_for :users
devise_for :admins
```

Now after rake routes to should see paths for both models.

Comment: devise_for :biz_users devise_for :users  I removed the devise_scope routes from the routes.rb file just now.

Comment: The :users model is routing to it's appropriate views from what I can see.

Comment: users and admins are the examples, If your models are users and biz_users you should do device_for :users, and device_for :biz_users, generally you should do device_for for each devise model. Now if you make rake routes you should get paths for each model.